# What is the origin of 'aqualung'?

Tags: synonyms

I don't mean the diving equipment, but used as a synonym to 'homeless man'. Is it used as a common phrase or just an invention of Ian Anderson.

Comment: Interesting. I did not know this meaning of the word at all, never heard it before. The diving equipment is the only sense of the word I'm familiar with.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, it's the name of an album (and the title song) from the 70's progressive rock group Jethro Tull.

Comment: What does your research show, Katel? Is there any documented usage of the word, excluding for the diving equipment, prior to the release date of the album?

Comment: Well, had tried to find one, but without success, all the references I have found are related either to breathing device or Jethro Tull album, song, interviews etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without evidence, I think it was invented by Ian Anderson.

I don't see it so much as simply a homeless person but as a homeless person with some kind of horrible deep wet cough, "spitting up pieces of his broken luck". Hence, aqua (water) + lung.

Answer (score 2):

This was [invented by Ian Anderson](http://www.rockcellarmagazine.com/2013/10/03/top-11-songs-about-being-broke/#sthash.Me79McZa.dpbs):

From the linked-to article:

> The idea came about from a photograph my wife at the time took of a tramp in London. I had feelings of guilt about the homeless, as well as fear and insecurity with people like that who seem a little scary. And I suppose all of that was combined with a slightly romanticized picture of the person who is homeless but yet a free spirit, who either won’t or can’t join in society’s prescribed formats. So from that photograph and those sentiments, I began writing the words to Aqualung.”
>
> Anderson, who imagined homeless men would have breathing problems, named the title character after the famous brand of undersea breathing gear used by divers.

Answer (score 1):

As quoted by [Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aqualung_(song)) from a 1999 interview with Ian Anderson in *Guitar World*:

> Aqualung wasn't a concept album, although a lot of people thought so. The idea came about from a photograph my wife at the time took of a tramp in London. I had feelings of guilt about the homeless, as well as fear and insecurity with people like that who seem a little scary. And I suppose all of that was combined with a slightly romanticized picture of the person who is homeless but yet a free spirit, who either won't or can't join in society's prescribed formats.
>
> So from that photograph and those sentiments, I began writing the words to "Aqualung". I can remember sitting in a hotel room in L.A., working out the chord structure for the verses. It's quite a tortured tangle of chords, but it was meant to really drag you here and there and then set you down into the more gentle acoustic section of the song.

He doesn't go so far as to explain the direct meaning in that quote. But [Songfacts](http://www.songfacts.com/detail.php?id=1422) says he envisioned the man getting an aqualung for his breathing problems.